# How to add an ndarray to another ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, embedding

I wish to add an array into another one. I've tried different techniques like append, extend, and even vstack, but I continuously get errors.

Clarifying into my project, I am using Facenet to create embeddings out of faces detected from a webcam. The embeddings are 128 dimensional. Additionally, I created a dataset of 26 faces, all of which are loaded as embeddings of the same dimensionality.

Firstly, the dataset embeddings are loaded into a variable called Data_1. Later on, this will be used to create t-SNE plots to visualize the data. The plot works well, but I want to be able to compare how a face from my webcam will compare to the dataset's points

Here's the code:

```
def detembed():
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    _,frame = cam.read()
    info = fd.detect_faces(frame)
    if info != []:
        for i in info:
            x,y,w,h = i['box']
            x,y = abs(x), abs(y)
            w,h = abs(w), abs(h)
            xx, yy = x+w, y+h
            #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (xx,yy), (0,0,255),2)
            face = frame[y:yy, x:xx]
            image = Image.fromarray(face)
            image = image.resize(size)
            arr = asarray(image)

            arr = arr.astype('float32')
            mean, std = arr.mean(), arr.std()
            arr = (arr - mean) / std
            samples = expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
            faces.append(samples)
        #cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)

while True:
    detembed()
    embeddings = Data_1
    if not faces:
        continue
    else:
        for face in faces:
            embeds = facenet.predict(face)
            print(embeds.shape, embeddings.shape)
            embeds = expand_dims(embeds, axis=0)
            embeddings = np.concatenate((embeddings,embeds), axis = 0 )

    points = TSNE(random_state=seed).fit_transform(embeddings)
```

I didn't want to fill the page with code, but just keep in mind I tried various methods (these being concatenate, append, extend, and insert) all to no avail. **Most of my errors occur with some array having a higher dimension**

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: You need to figure out the dimensions of the arrays first, and check that they match whatever the method of choice (`np.concatenate` for example) expects.  A debugger could help here; you could stop the code at the point where you are trying to join the arrays and check that the dimensions are what you expect. As a suggestion, Microsoft's Visual Studio Code is free and provides a Python debugger that actually works.

Comment: Yes, in the code I made it so that whenever the arrays were changed it would print its shape. I have 26 photos in the dataset so `embeddings` is `(26,128)` while the new embedding from the camera is `(1,128)`. It seems right, so I don't know whats wrong. I'll take your advice though :)